# jQuery draggable. Fullsize image draggable to its boundries within body?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

probably a simple task, but I don't know how to approach this.

I have a huge image (the image is dynamic and has different widths and heights) and I want it to always load centered vertically and centered horizontally on my page.

the image is always too big for the body to cover it so it overflows the page, but that is exactly what I want and need.

**TASK 1.)** 
I just need to automatically position it with the center of the image always vertically and horitontally centered within the body.

**TASK 2.)**
I want the image to be draggable, but exactly to its boundries.
So I want the image to be dragged till I for instance reach the upper right corner and it hits the corner of the viewport, but I don't want it do be draggable further.

-> http://jsfiddle.net/3j40b4u1/

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="draggable" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Flower_jtca001.jpg" alt="image"/>
</div>
```

So this should not be possible … https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3p2P222S2d163N1R0v2M/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-04%20at%2018.53.47.png

This is what should be possible … 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/1i3o462l2Z3t3t3z1v0m/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-04%20at%2018.54.42.png

How would i do this?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so simple to achieve it, but let us try. First we need to inject code to our "drag" event, we force it not to go out of our boundaries:

```
drag : function(e,ui) {
    //Force the helper position
    if (ui.position.left > 0) {
        ui.position.left = 0;
    }
    if (ui.position.top > 0) {
        ui.position.top = 0;
    }
}
```

Then the second part, centering an image. You can achieve it in dozens of ways - all you have to remember is to invoke it on "create" event of our draggable method:

```
create: function (event, ui) {
    var img = $(".draggable")
    ,   imgWidth  = img.width()
    ,   imgHeight = img.height();

    img.css("position","absolute");
    img.css("top", Math.min(0, ($(window).height() - imgWidth / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    img.css("left", Math.min(0, ($(window).width() - imgHeight / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");

}
```

Here, that's all! Not so complicated.

http://jsfiddle.net/3j40b4u1/4/

Comment: thank you, how would would i do that for the upper right corner as well? So i want it to be dragged only till the upper right corner hits the viewport (body) as well.

Comment: @matt Basically you'll need to operate on ui.position.left and body's outerWidth, cause these are the values we've have. Let's try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/3j40b4u1/5/

Comment: @matt If I helped you, please accept/upvote my answers.

Comment: thank you, for me this doesn't work. The image will always be wider and higher as the body cause this thing is about huge images that can simply be dragged around within its boundaries. If I click the image jumps … https://cl.ly/a54M and I can move it further than the lower right corner.

Comment: @matt Well, you should describe your questions more precisely ;-) I thought, that all you wanted was to swipe the rules for left-right margins. Here's what you wanted to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/3j40b4u1/6/

Comment: @matt Please notice, that I've set body height to constant value. If you want it to stay fluid, than you should save and initial height of your viewport somewhere in a visible namespace, so you will have an access to unmodified value later on.

Comment: thank you @eeree but again it does not really work as expected … https://cl.ly/a6XW (the lower right corner is not the lower right corner.) it somewhere in the middle of the image and it's also 20px from the bottom possible. It should really work only to move the image and never see a background of the body. Imagine the body is red, there should never be a case where red is visible, but every pixel of the image shuold be visible.

Comment: also the body and container should be 100% wide and high in order to also work responsive and work on every device.

Comment: @matt You should know, that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. The first issue you described comes from no CSS in JSFiddle. Just configure the padding and margin respectively and your issue will be gone. Second issue should be done by applying correct styles to your frames. That's all.